# Asymptotic expansions of solutions of nonlinear PDE's

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

Let's consider the following Cauchy problem:

$$u_t=\alpha(x,t,u)u_{xx}+\beta(x,t,u)(u_x)^2+\gamma(x,t,u)u_x+\phi(x,t,u)$$

$$u(x,0)=u_0(x).$$

Assume that functions $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\phi$ are regular (Hölder continous or even smooth but may have some sort of singularity in $t=0$ like $1/t$ term for example). Suppose that we can prove that this problem has unique solution $u=u(x,t)$ in some domain $D\subset\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}_+$.

Im interested in short time symptotic expansions of solutions, i.e. im looking for methods of showing that 
$$u(x,t)=\Sigma_{k=0}^mu^k(x)t^k+o(t^m)$$
as $t\rightarrow 0$.
(With description of functions $u^k$ in terms of simpler PDE's of course).

My question is: are there any papers or monographs dealing with such asymptotic expansions in case of complicated nonlinear PDE's (with mathematical rigour, not only clever Ansatz coming out of the blue and with no proof)?

Another problem I'm concerned with:

In various works i saw asymptotic expansion technique was used in following manner:

1) Write down a series $\Sigma_{i=0}^{\infty}\lambda^iu_i(x,t)$, where $\lambda$ is time variable or some synthetic parameter

2) Plug that formal series into equation, perform differential operations term by term, group everything by powers of $\lambda$

3)Observe that coefficients standing by powers of $\lambda$ are differential operators applied to unknown functions $u_0,u_1,u_2,...$

4)Solve system of equations obtained by equating those coefficients to $0$

5)Be happy that you solved initial equation

So here is a basic question:
how can we be sure without any further analysis between points 4) and 5) that obtained series is in any way related to actual solution?

In some papers i saw (physics and mathematical finance) authors just obtained that formal series and didn't even bother with proving that it has anythin to do with actual solution. Why?

Here is an example of a problem im trying to "assymptotically expand" in short time:

$$tu_t=Tr[\frac{u}{2}AD(\frac{x}{u})\otimes D(\frac{x}{u})]-t^2Tr[\frac{u^3}{8}ADu\otimes Du]+t<\alpha,Du>+t Tr[\frac{1}{2}AD^2u]-\frac{u}{2}$$
Where: $u=u(x,y,t)$ ($x,y>0$ $t\geq 0$) -solution (assume that it exists and that $u>0$),
$A=A(x,y,t)$ -is $2\times 2$ matrix for all $x,y,t$ and its is Hölder continous with exponent $\alpha$ in space and $\alpha/2$ in time, $\alpha=\alpha(x,y,t)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ also Hölder continous with exponent $\alpha$ in space variables and $\alpha/2$ in time variable. $Tr$ stand for trace of a matrix and $\otimes$ for tensor product of vectors: $(a_{i})\otimes (b_{i})=(a_i b_j)_{i,j}$ ($a,b$ -vectors, $a\otimes b$ -matrix).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most direct way to get a small time expansion is using a gradient expansion. This can be worked out in the following way. Rescale your time variable as $t\rightarrow\lambda t$ being $\lambda$ a parameter taken to be arbitrary large and introduced to fix expansion order. Then, takes $\phi$ proportional to $\lambda$. You will get

$$\lambda u_\tau=\alpha(x,\frac{\tau}{\lambda},u)u_{xx}+\beta(x,\frac{\tau}{\lambda},u)(u_x)^2+\gamma(x,\frac{\tau}{\lambda},u)u_x+\lambda\phi(x,\frac{\tau}{\lambda},u).$$

Then, expand $u$ as

$$u(x,\tau)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{\lambda^n}u_n(x,\tau).$$

At the end of the computation just put $\lambda=1$. Your solution will be given as polynomials in $t$.

Now, let us consider your equation

$$tu_t=Tr[\frac{u}{2}AD(\frac{x}{u})\otimes D(\frac{x}{u})]-t^2Tr[\frac{u^3}{8}ADu\otimes Du]+t&lt;\alpha,Du>$$

$$+t Tr[\frac{1}{2}AD^2u]-\frac{u}{2}.$$

We firstly note that $D(\frac{x}{u})=\frac{e_x}{u}-x\frac{Du}{u^2}$ and so we can write down this equation in the form

$$tu_t=\frac{1}{2u}[A_{xx}+x^2Tr[A Du\otimes Du]]-t^2Tr[\frac{u^3}{8}ADu\otimes  Du]+t<\alpha,Du>$$

$$+t Tr[\frac{1}{2}AD^2u]-\frac{u}{2}.$$

I hope I have interpreted correctly your notation. Now, multiply by $u$ both sides and you will get

$$tuu_t=\frac{1}{2}[A_{xx}+x^2Tr[A Du\otimes Du]]-t^2uTr[\frac{u^3}{8}ADu\otimes Du]+t<\alpha,Du>$$

$$+t uTr[\frac{1}{2}AD^2u]-\frac{u^2}{2}.$$

Now, change the variable as $\tau=\lambda t$. You will get the new equation

$$\tau uu_\tau=\frac{1}{2}[A_{xx}+x^2Tr[A Du\otimes Du]]-\frac{1}{\lambda^2}\tau^2uTr[\frac{u^3}{8}ADu\otimes Du]+\frac{1}{\lambda}\tau <\alpha,Du>$$

$$+\frac{1}{\lambda}\tau uTr[\frac{1}{2}AD^2u]-\frac{u^2}{2}.$$

From this you can read off immediately the leading order being

$$\tau u_0u_{0\tau}=\frac{1}{2}[A_{xx}+x^2Tr[A Du_0\otimes Du_0]]-\frac{u_0^2}{2}.$$

This is a Hamilton-Jacobi equation that can be solved by the characteristic method. Higher orders can be obtained straightforwardly as an expansion in $\frac{1}{\lambda}$.

We can spend a few words about the next-to-leading order by substituting into the scaled equation

$$u=u_0+\frac{1}{\lambda}u_1+O\left(\frac{1}{\lambda^2}\right)$$

Then, the equation becomes

$$\tau (u_0+\frac{1}{\lambda}u_1)(u_{0\tau}+\frac{1}{\lambda}u_{1\tau})=\frac{1}{2}[A_{xx}+x^2Tr[A D(u_0+\frac{1}{\lambda}u_1)\otimes D(u_0+\frac{1}{\lambda}u_1)]]-$$

$$\frac{1}{\lambda^2}\tau^2(u_0+\frac{1}{\lambda}u_1)Tr[\frac{(u_0+\frac{1}{\lambda}u_1)^3}{8}AD(u_0+\frac{1}{\lambda}u_1)\otimes D(u_0+\frac{1}{\lambda}u_1)]$$

$$+\frac{1}{\lambda}\tau <\alpha,D(u_0+\frac{1}{\lambda}u_1)>$$

$$+\frac{1}{\lambda}\tau (u_0+\frac{1}{\lambda}u_1)Tr[\frac{1}{2}AD^2(u_0+\frac{1}{\lambda}u_1)]-\frac{1}{2}\left(u_0+\frac{1}{\lambda}u_1\right)^2+O\left(\frac{1}{\lambda^2}\right).$$

So, the equation to compute $u_1$ is

$$\tau (u_0u_{1\tau}+u_1u_{0\tau})=x^2Tr[A Du_0\otimes Du_1]$$

$$-\tau <\alpha,Du_0>+\tau u_0Tr[\frac{1}{2}AD^2u_0]-u_0u_1.$$

One can repeat this procedure at any order and, finally, gets the solution into the form given at the beginning of this post.

Comment: Does it really work in case of nonlinear equations?

Even in case of equation like: $u_t=\frac{1}{u^2}u_{xx}+\frac{1}{u^4}(u_x)^2$ where functions $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\phi$ are very simple rational functions inserting series into equation leads to terms that cant be ordered in polynomial fashion. (in case of rational functions i can of course multiply by denominators, but what in case of something like logarithm ?)


Comment: @Pawel: I worked this out also for Yang-Mills equations and it works fine. It is a technique to get a gradient expansion. Of course, in your case, I would write (for $u\ne 0$) $u^4u_t=u^2u_{xx}+(u_x)^2$, then the leading order gives $u_0^4u_{0t}=0$ that is meaningful and so higher orders. But maybe one of he best applications can be found for $\square u+u^3=0$. Doing as I said, you get the leading order equation $\partial_t^2 u_0+u_0^3=0$ that is exactly solvable.

Comment: Ok, I see it works in case of that example. The problem is that equations im currently working on are more complicated (they are in many dimensions, highly nonlinear: they involve more complicated rational functions of unknown and its variables). Could you reccomend me some sources where I can see those techniques explained?


Comment: @Could you give an example of such equations? Maybe there is a straightforward way to do a gradient expansion on it. I would add to my answer to make it more helpful.

Comment: Also please look on second part of my post: is it obvious that we are getting series that is in any way related to actual true solution of our problem? Im quite sure that i even saw divergent " series solutions". Why noone cares if "solution" obtained in such a manner really defines a true solution? Or is it obvious and I just dont quite get all that black magic?

Comment: This is the foundation of the perturbation technique. Indeed, often this series is just an asymptotic one. In any case, it represents the best approximation ever to a solution to the given equation. So, I will give you here a standard reference for this but I think people here have a lot of their preferred textbooks for this: J.Kevorkian, J.D.Cole, Perturbation Methods in Applied Mathematics, (Springer-Verlag, New York, 1985). I have introduced the above technique firstly for Einstein equations in http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0508246 .

Comment: Thank you for references. I added my actual equation in main post.

Comment: @Pawel: I have worked out your example. I hope to have correctly understood your notation. It is a fine example for a gradient expansion as the leading order is a Hamilton-Jacobi equation.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer is very helpful.

May I just ask you to write about higher order expansion in just little more detail? (I'am unfamiliar with such techniques and don't see all things immidietly...)

Also how does this expansion relates to actual solution?



Comment: Ok, I will write some rows about higher order terms. A gradient expansion generally provides a small time expansion of the real solution or, at best, an asymptotic approximation to it. Also, a gradient expansion is dual to a standard small perturbation series meaning with this that the same parameter of the series should be now considered increasingly large as you can see from my post and the paper I have cited.

Comment: Now I'm quite convinced that method you just presented can handle such nonlinearities. Also you encouraged me to learn more about that gradient expansion technique :) Thank you very much again, great answer!

Answer (score 2):

I am not 100% sure, but the following monograph may be relevant:

Satyanad Kichenassamy, *Fuchsian reduction: applications to geometry, cosmology and mathematical physics* (Springer, 2007)

http://books.google.nl/books?id=YnH-39QSbQsC